# Python exercise using a dictionary to implement withdrawals and deposits to bank accounts

Tags: python, dictionary, account

I'm a beginner in Python programming, therefore I'm following a course where we have to submit assignments every week.

The current assignment is to write a program where the user can Open, and Close and account, can Deposit and Withdraw money, and List the accounts (i.e. view all accounts and balance according to specific account).

My main problem is that the balance (which starts at 0) is the same for every account, while every account should have its own balance!

I came this far:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
def print_menu():
    print "1. List Account(s)"
    print "2. Open an Account"
    print "3. Close an Account"
    print "4. Withdraw money"
    print "5. Deposit Money"
    print "6. Quit"
    print

accounts = {}
menu_choice = 0
print_menu()
#balance = {}
balance = 0
while True:
    menu_choice = int(input("Type in a number (1-6): "))
    print
    if menu_choice == 1:
        print "Accounts"
        for x in accounts.keys():
            print "Accountnumber:", x, "with balance €", balance
        print
    elif menu_choice == 2:
        print "Enter a new Accountnumber"
        number = input("New accountnumber: ")
        #phone = input("Number: ")
        accounts[number]=balance
        print "Accountnumber", number, "opened."
    elif menu_choice == 3:
        print "Close an Accountnumber"
        number = input("Accountnumber: ")
        if number in accounts:
            #accounts[number]=balance
            del accounts[number]
            print "Accountnumber", number, "is closed."
        else:
            print "Accountnumber", number, "was not found"
    #elif menu_choice == 4:
        #print("Lookup Number")
        #name = input("Name: ")
        #if name in numbers:
        #    print("The number is", numbers[name])
        #else:
        #    print(name, "was not found")
    elif menu_choice == 4:
        print "Withdraw money from Account."
        number = input("Accoutnnumber: ")
        if number in accounts:
            withdraw = float(input("How much money would you like to withdraw? > "))
            if withdraw < balance:
                #accounts[number]=balance
                numbers[balance] -= withdraw
                #balance vann number 444 bijv. !!
                print "Your new balance is €", balance
            else:
                print "There are no sufficient funds on this accountnumber"
    elif menu_choice == 5:
        print "Deposit money onto Account."
        number = input("Accountnumber: ")
        if number in accounts:
            deposit = float(input("How much money would you like to deposit? > "))
            #accounts[number]=balance
            balance += deposit
            #balance vannn number 444 bijv. !!
            print "Your new balance is €", balance
        else:
            print "That accountnumber does not exist."
    elif menu_choice == 6:
        print "Quit."
        break
    else:
        print "Please enter a number between 1 and 6."
    print
    print_menu()

# Ook nog ff instellen dat wanneer input geen iets anders is,
# dan gewoon netjes afluisten, geen rare foutcodes !!
```

Comment: I would recommend taking an object oriented approach to this. An Account seems like it would make a great object, and could have attributes like numbers, name, and balance. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm) On how to get started with classes. If you'd like I can answer with some more suggestions.

Comment: Robin, probably they have not reached Objects in their course. They are using dictionaries, arrays and so on :) , the rudiments of the language.

Comment: JoseM is right, I really haven't reached Objects yet (read about it on the internet though). So I guess school wouldn't allow me to submit it that way.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using "balance" in a wrong way. It's far better if you use accounts like a dictionary, where you have "accounts numbers" and "balance".

This way if you have something like:

```
accounts = {1:100, 2:1500, 3:0}
```

that means that the person with account numbered 1 has 100$, the second person with acc number 2 has 1500 and so on.

For example in choice 4 you are doing this:

```
elif menu_choice == 4:
        print "Withdraw money from Account."
        number = input("Accoutnnumber: ")
        if number in accounts:
            withdraw = float(input("How much money would you like to withdraw? > "))
            if withdraw < balance:
                #accounts[number]=balance
                numbers[balance] -= withdraw
                #balance vann number 444 bijv. !!
                print "Your new balance is €", balance
            else:
                print "There are no sufficient funds on this accountnumber"
```

But this is better:

```
elif menu_choice == 4:
        print "Withdraw money from Account."
        number = input("Accoutnnumber: ")
        if number in accounts:
            withdraw = float(input("How much money would you like to withdraw? > "))
            balance = accounts[number]
            if withdraw < balance:
                accounts[number] -=withdraw 
                print "Your new balance is €", accounts[number]
            else:
                print "There are no sufficient funds on this accountnumber"
```

I hope this help with your homework.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help! The thing is, however, the user should be able to create an account (for example 444) and the account created by the user should have a balance of its own. So it should be possible that the user firstly opens 4 accounts, namely 444, 333, 222, 111 and then, for example, deposits $10 on accountnr 444, deposits $50 on accountnr 222. That means that accountnr 444 has a balance of $10, and accountnr 222 has a balance of $50.And that, the user should be able to view by List Accounts (all the accounts that are currently opened are showed with their own balances.